# Count animation doesn't work properly when scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I'm making the animation counting numbers feature when the scroll reaches the id, in this case `id="countAnimation"`.

I've made a code like the one below, but the problem is, when the scroll has reached the id, it will count fine but when scrolling up and back scrolling down the numbers will be `0`, when trying to scroll up and down again the numbers are not correct numbers like `200`,`20.5`,`1500`.

I want the number animation to count only once when the scroll reaches the id. not over and over.

Where is the missing code or error from the code that I've made? Please help me

```js
function countNumber(){
$('.count').each(function() {
      var countTo = Number($(this).text())

      $(this).prop('Counter', 0).animate({
         Counter: countTo - 1
      }, {
         duration: 4000,
         easing: 'swing',
         step: function(now) {
               var ceil = Math.ceil(now)
               if (ceil < countTo) {
                    $(this).text(ceil);
               }
         },
         complete: function() {
              $(this).text(countTo);
         }
     });
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {

   var offsetTop = $("#countAnimation").offset().top;

   $(window).scroll(function() {
       var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
       
       if (scrollTop > offsetTop) { //run function count number when reach maps content id
           countNumber();
       }
  });
});
```

```css
#countAnimation {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-bottom:200px;
}

.box-counter {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #cacaca;
  color: #0f0f0f;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0px 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="description">
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Corrupti exercitationem cupiditate sed ab quo quas eum quidem sunt, sit modi ex at beatae sequi quisquam, quos commodi amet nobis obcaecati. Et laborum non fugiat ea, asperiores enim doloremque magni aliquid optio repellat quisquam cum, officiis recusandae explicabo nihil iure, molestiae modi? Velit numquam ea rerum, repellendus ut dignissimos deleniti nesciunt nulla voluptates iure perferendis impedit similique, libero beatae eius incidunt repellat cupiditate inventore? Soluta ab iure animi earum ducimus unde incidunt odio! Molestias officiis vero, vitae magni nostrum eaque necessitatibus! Unde necessitatibus fugit dolorem dolores praesentium vitae perspiciatis voluptate placeat ex voluptates ipsum, molestias omnis, sit mollitia veritatis aliquam, quisquam pariatur molestiae. Aperiam, atque rem alias libero similique esse natus nulla culpa? Eligendi dolorem accusantium ratione dolores beatae, cum reiciendis esse ut, necessitatibus iusto consequatur deserunt quaerat in ullam minus harum impedit quas aperiam assumenda fuga, ad iste. Illo fugit aliquid consequuntur nobis odio perferendis eum, alias cupiditate ipsam, laboriosam soluta unde velit nam doloremque ipsa a provident adipisci. Doloribus, iure quisquam fugit maxime minima repellendus omnis reiciendis culpa mollitia, temporibus quis eius libero sed odit atque aperiam beatae dignissimos sit architecto, id recusandae et blanditiis quae commodi? Unde fuga officia, in assumenda sint cupiditate quidem molestias distinctio! Incidunt quis, cupiditate natus aut placeat ducimus ex nostrum, voluptatibus voluptatem facilis cumque eius recusandae fugiat sed. Quam dolorum iste quaerat voluptatum inventore harum voluptas facere totam optio nobis! Nostrum tempora quibusdam voluptate ipsum autem. Aperiam soluta aut cum obcaecati omnis qui repellat debitis ratione, temporibus est nemo ipsam, hic earum id voluptatibus at, asperiores corrupti quasi sed ab ullam iusto quam? Quo, quae nesciunt ut ratione distinctio, magnam id consequatur, culpa cum sapiente odit ullam. Rerum explicabo doloremque neque error eius suscipit minima consequatur! Consequatur laudantium voluptas enim minima hic sint aspernatur animi, dolor mollitia facere ab. Provident suscipit aut dolorum aliquam at, tempore quas possimus fugit? Harum vel suscipit tempora eveniet earum nobis maiores incidunt pariatur molestiae. Eveniet, quae rem perspiciatis id laudantium dolores laborum blanditiis reiciendis, architecto dolor nostrum impedit laboriosam officia placeat deserunt doloribus, suscipit fuga quidem necessitatibus sunt. Saepe iste eos amet, modi nisi doloribus sit atque dolores odio sunt id quas quasi quidem repellendus eveniet ducimus rem laboriosam dolore. Cupiditate nesciunt quibusdam dolore odio distinctio reprehenderit maxime voluptatibus quo exercitationem, numquam sapiente ab est repellat odit. Illum, cupiditate! Numquam cumque, exercitationem iusto soluta voluptate doloribus sint repellat expedita at placeat facilis nostrum veniam beatae velit est quae sapiente ut atque enim magni. Voluptate, perferendis architecto qui nemo necessitatibus saepe dolores temporibus tempore facilis omnis nulla distinctio, eveniet cum praesentium, autem molestiae reprehenderit numquam itaque ipsum excepturi laboriosam. Rerum, cupiditate aliquam. Saepe voluptates perferendis vero facere, officia voluptate tempora, labore ab, sed est expedita cum sequi ut amet excepturi. Praesentium error dicta, a debitis vitae, unde repellat officia recusandae molestias sit itaque non atque eaque ipsam tempore iure quo laboriosam, sunt dolorum quibusdam veritatis laudantium? Neque corporis soluta laborum! Nihil, ab illo labore ipsam veniam cumque quisquam deleniti ut totam voluptas illum neque cupiditate fugit autem at adipisci esse. Voluptatibus aperiam dicta itaque maxime suscipit. Ducimus quod velit neque quae quia quis eligendi, illum harum laboriosam corrupti eveniet ipsum, ipsam obcaecati hic atque porro recusandae commodi tenetur similique excepturi cum ab! Asperiores impedit ex corporis eveniet minima placeat eos deserunt ab ratione assumenda accusamus reiciendis earum iusto, non voluptatum in at eaque repellat dolorum reprehenderit. Pariatur atque quidem voluptas debitis consequatur non amet, est maiores dignissimos unde earum? Incidunt placeat velit soluta, et consequuntur ipsa maxime reprehenderit doloremque minus beatae animi odit repudiandae sint ipsam rerum atque, eaque ea, unde nobis? Provident nostrum sequi quidem molestias mollitia voluptates harum, debitis eveniet pariatur a doloremque illum at culpa ullam assumenda sed dolore! Voluptatum corporis quis adipisci voluptate itaque nisi qui quam ratione minima repudiandae hic eveniet distinctio harum assumenda, nam quas ullam deleniti quidem quae magnam sit ducimus exercitationem commodi quo! Reiciendis vel ex dolorem reprehenderit, deleniti aperiam perferendis quos quas veniam at! Iusto officiis pariatur, nemo totam architecto consequuntur rem itaque? Quos recusandae iste accusantium voluptates debitis odit ut cum asperiores minus fugiat molestias ipsa aliquid animi delectus harum explicabo quisquam a similique natus nulla reprehenderit optio, id eos! Porro laboriosam minus amet nisi, vero reprehenderit tempore qui dignissimos, nemo fugiat cumque sapiente nulla aliquid ab eveniet, facilis dolores repellendus veniam beatae! Similique voluptatibus quis fugiat inventore ipsam, ex distinctio voluptas ea in quod eveniet dicta soluta!
  </p>
</div>
<div id="countAnimation">
  <div class="box-counter">
    <div class="count">200</div>
  </div>
  <div class="box-counter">
    <div class="count">20.5</div>
  </div>
  <div class="box-counter">
    <div class="count">1500</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You could simply add a class once you trigger the counting animation to indicate it was triggered. Now you can check if an element already has this class before you trigger the animation.

Comment: and how is it? can you give me an example from my code above? @DB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you to handle this using a flag, keep track if the countNumbers is called or not. If it is called then just mark it as false,

Please use the following logic in your code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   let isCountNumbersCalled = false;
   var offsetTop = $("#countAnimation").offset().top;

   $(window).scroll(function() {
       var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
       
       if (scrollTop > offsetTop) { //run function count number when reach maps content id
           !isCountNumbersCalled && countNumber();
            isCountNumbersCalled = true;
       }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to change the condition of scrolling just let the variable checking it.

```js
function countNumber(){
$('.count').each(function() {
      var countTo = Number($(this).text())

      $(this).prop('Counter', 0).animate({
         Counter: countTo - 1
      }, {
         duration: 4000,
         easing: 'swing',
         step: function(now) {
               var ceil = Math.ceil(now)
               if (ceil < countTo) {
                    $(this).text(ceil);
               }
         },
         complete: function() {
              $(this).text(countTo);
         }
     });
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {

   var offsetTop = $("#countAnimation").offset().top;

   $(window).scroll(function() {
       var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
       let notCounted = true;
       if (scrollTop > offsetTop && notCounted) { //run function count number when reach maps content id
           countNumber();
           notCounted = false;
       }
  });
});
```

```css
#countAnimation {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-bottom:200px;
}

.box-counter {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #cacaca;
  color: #0f0f0f;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0px 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="description">
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Corrupti exercitationem cupiditate sed ab quo quas eum quidem sunt, sit modi ex at beatae sequi quisquam, quos commodi amet nobis obcaecati. Et laborum non fugiat ea, asperiores enim doloremque magni aliquid optio repellat quisquam cum, officiis recusandae explicabo nihil iure, molestiae modi? Velit numquam ea rerum, repellendus ut dignissimos deleniti nesciunt nulla voluptates iure perferendis impedit similique, libero beatae eius incidunt repellat cupiditate inventore? Soluta ab iure animi earum ducimus unde incidunt odio! Molestias officiis vero, vitae magni nostrum eaque necessitatibus! Unde necessitatibus fugit dolorem dolores praesentium vitae perspiciatis voluptate placeat ex voluptates ipsum, molestias omnis, sit mollitia veritatis aliquam, quisquam pariatur molestiae. Aperiam, atque rem alias libero similique esse natus nulla culpa? Eligendi dolorem accusantium ratione dolores beatae, cum reiciendis esse ut, necessitatibus iusto consequatur deserunt quaerat in ullam minus harum impedit quas aperiam assumenda fuga, ad iste. Illo fugit aliquid consequuntur nobis odio perferendis eum, alias cupiditate ipsam, laboriosam soluta unde velit nam doloremque ipsa a provident adipisci. Doloribus, iure quisquam fugit maxime minima repellendus omnis reiciendis culpa mollitia, temporibus quis eius libero sed odit atque aperiam beatae dignissimos sit architecto, id recusandae et blanditiis quae commodi? Unde fuga officia, in assumenda sint cupiditate quidem molestias distinctio! Incidunt quis, cupiditate natus aut placeat ducimus ex nostrum, voluptatibus voluptatem facilis cumque eius recusandae fugiat sed. Quam dolorum iste quaerat voluptatum inventore harum voluptas facere totam optio nobis! Nostrum tempora quibusdam voluptate ipsum autem. Aperiam soluta aut cum obcaecati omnis qui repellat debitis ratione, temporibus est nemo ipsam, hic earum id voluptatibus at, asperiores corrupti quasi sed ab ullam iusto quam? Quo, quae nesciunt ut ratione distinctio, magnam id consequatur, culpa cum sapiente odit ullam. Rerum explicabo doloremque neque error eius suscipit minima consequatur! Consequatur laudantium voluptas enim minima hic sint aspernatur animi, dolor mollitia facere ab. Provident suscipit aut dolorum aliquam at, tempore quas possimus fugit? Harum vel suscipit tempora eveniet earum nobis maiores incidunt pariatur molestiae. Eveniet, quae rem perspiciatis id laudantium dolores laborum blanditiis reiciendis, architecto dolor nostrum impedit laboriosam officia placeat deserunt doloribus, suscipit fuga quidem necessitatibus sunt. Saepe iste eos amet, modi nisi doloribus sit atque dolores odio sunt id quas quasi quidem repellendus eveniet ducimus rem laboriosam dolore. Cupiditate nesciunt quibusdam dolore odio distinctio reprehenderit maxime voluptatibus quo exercitationem, numquam sapiente ab est repellat odit. Illum, cupiditate! Numquam cumque, exercitationem iusto soluta voluptate doloribus sint repellat expedita at placeat facilis nostrum veniam beatae velit est quae sapiente ut atque enim magni. Voluptate, perferendis architecto qui nemo necessitatibus saepe dolores temporibus tempore facilis omnis nulla distinctio, eveniet cum praesentium, autem molestiae reprehenderit numquam itaque ipsum excepturi laboriosam. Rerum, cupiditate aliquam. Saepe voluptates perferendis vero facere, officia voluptate tempora, labore ab, sed est expedita cum sequi ut amet excepturi. Praesentium error dicta, a debitis vitae, unde repellat officia recusandae molestias sit itaque non atque eaque ipsam tempore iure quo laboriosam, sunt dolorum quibusdam veritatis laudantium? Neque corporis soluta laborum! Nihil, ab illo labore ipsam veniam cumque quisquam deleniti ut totam voluptas illum neque cupiditate fugit autem at adipisci esse. Voluptatibus aperiam dicta itaque maxime suscipit. Ducimus quod velit neque quae quia quis eligendi, illum harum laboriosam corrupti eveniet ipsum, ipsam obcaecati hic atque porro recusandae commodi tenetur similique excepturi cum ab! Asperiores impedit ex corporis eveniet minima placeat eos deserunt ab ratione assumenda accusamus reiciendis earum iusto, non voluptatum in at eaque repellat dolorum reprehenderit. Pariatur atque quidem voluptas debitis consequatur non amet, est maiores dignissimos unde earum? Incidunt placeat velit soluta, et consequuntur ipsa maxime reprehenderit doloremque minus beatae animi odit repudiandae sint ipsam rerum atque, eaque ea, unde nobis? Provident nostrum sequi quidem molestias mollitia voluptates harum, debitis eveniet pariatur a doloremque illum at culpa ullam assumenda sed dolore! Voluptatum corporis quis adipisci voluptate itaque nisi qui quam ratione minima repudiandae hic eveniet distinctio harum assumenda, nam quas ullam deleniti quidem quae magnam sit ducimus exercitationem commodi quo! Reiciendis vel ex dolorem reprehenderit, deleniti aperiam perferendis quos quas veniam at! Iusto officiis pariatur, nemo totam architecto consequuntur rem itaque? Quos recusandae iste accusantium voluptates debitis odit ut cum asperiores minus fugiat molestias ipsa aliquid animi delectus harum explicabo quisquam a similique natus nulla reprehenderit optio, id eos! Porro laboriosam minus amet nisi, vero reprehenderit tempore qui dignissimos, nemo fugiat cumque sapiente nulla aliquid ab eveniet, facilis dolores repellendus veniam beatae! Similique voluptatibus quis fugiat inventore ipsam, ex distinctio voluptas ea in quod eveniet dicta soluta!
  </p>
</div>
<div id="countAnimation">
  <div class="box-counter">
    <div class="count">200</div>
  </div>
  <div class="box-counter">
    <div class="count">20.5</div>
  </div>
  <div class="box-counter">
    <div class="count">1500</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i'm trying scroll up and scroll down for few times, the numbers become ```-1```, ```-1```,```-1```

Answer (score 0):

You should mark an element as "animated" once you have started animing it. This should be a flag on each element itself in case you have multiple counter at different heights.

```
$('.count').each(function() {
  if (this.animated === true) {
        return;
  }
  this.animated = true;
  // Your animation is here
 });
```